# How to call a function from custom pallet using api.tx?

Tags: polkadot-js, custom-rpc

I made a custom pallet and wants to access its method using a extrinsic call like `api.tx.<module>.<method>` but was not able to do that, do i need to implement it in blockchain code or it is implemented already but i am doing something wrong.

Comment: By custom pallet, I assume you mean you created a custom RPC to call on a method. Is that correct?

Comment: No not created rpc just want to use it as other api.tx calls are being made